# I'm trying to plot TagName(x) relative to Depth(y) but dont know how to

Tags: r, variables, plot

Trying to make a simple plot but have no idea how to set up

My data:

```
AveragDiveDepth <- read.table(text= "
TagName Depth 
234798 15.37 
234800 14.95 
234801 19.07 
234802 17.17 
234803 17.57 
234804 29.05 
234805 17.79", header=TRUE)
```

I'm having a hard time setting up my x and y variables. I don't know how to assign my data as variables. I tried looking at plots online however none of the way their plots were set up applied to my simple plot.